# Excess in use of Packet data after updating Google play store

Tags: google-play-store, updates, samsung-galaxy-y-duos

I have been using Samsung Galaxy Y Duos.

Last week I've updated the version of Google Play Store. From that time on, the internet packet data usage has hugely increased, it is consuming a lot of packet data in background and even the battery time had reduced to half of what it was before.

I would like to know if there is some issue with the newest version of the Play Store.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add Play Store version number.

Comment: There was a notification that a new version of play store is available and then i updated to that version. Is there any way to find the version number manually

Comment: Play Store >> Settings >> Build Version

Comment: Have you disabled automatic app updates in the Play Store settings?

Comment: I've heard anecdotally of people having excess data downloading by Android OS recently, but I haven't heard that Play Store was the cause. Chances are people are still figuring this out.